# Original List vs Edited List of objects; How to locate the edited items with linq?

Tags: c#, linq, list, compare, dto

I have an OrderDto class that implements the IEquatable interface.  I have a list of Orders that are retrieved from the database as OrderDto objects.  This list is edited by the end user... Adding new objects; Deleting existing objects; Editing existing objects.  I need to determine the following:

1. New objects in the list;
2. Deleted objects in the list;
3. Edited objects in the list;

I have commented the following code to discuss these three goals.  The first two are trivial, but the third item in my list is very vexing!  I cannot seem to create it using linq.  I hope that you can give me a nudge in the correct direction.  Please see the following code for details.

Thank you for your help!
Mike

```
// Get the original list of OrderDtos before the user did anything.
var entityOrders = Mapper.Map<IList<OrderEntity>, IList<OrderDto>>(entity.Orders.ToList());  

// dto.Orders is a parameter that is being used in this code.  It is the list of OrderDto
// objects that the user has modified: Insert, edit, delete.

// Works properly to locate items that were deleted.          
var deletedOrders = entityOrders.Except(dto.Orders);

// Works properly to locate items that were added.
var addedOrders = dto.Orders.Except(entityOrders);

// Determine the list of order objects less new orders in the list.
// The user has already deleted objects, so we don't have to worry
// about them.  This list will contain only items that MAY have 
// been edited.
var potentialChanges = dto.Orders.Except(addedOrders);

// ARGGG!  I cannot seem to get this one to work properly!  As you can see in the 
// definition of the OrderDto, it implements the IEquatable interface.  So, it 
// should be very easy to determine which items in the dto.Orders list have been
// edited as opposed to the original version in the entityOrders list.  What I 
// would like to have is a list of all the OrderDto objects in the dto.Orders list
// that have been modified.  Since OrderDto implements IEquatable, we should be able
// to compare OrderDto objects directly, but I have not been able get it to work.
// Please helP! :)
var changedOrders =
   from dtoOrder in potentialChanges
   let entityOrder = entityOrders.First(x => x.OrderId == dtoOrder.OrderId)
   where entityOrder != null && !dtoOrder.Equals(entityOrder)
   select dtoOrder;
```

Here is the definition of the OrderDto class...

```
public class OrderDto : IEquatable<OrderDto>
{
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayAs { get; set; }

    #region IEquatable
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // Populate with all fields so
        // we can detect when an entity
        // has been edited.
        return 
        (
            (int) OrderId ^ 
            DisplayAs.GetHashCode()
        );

    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return this.Equals(other as OrderDto);
    }

    public bool Equals(OrderDto other)
    {
        // Populate with all fields so
        // we can detect when an entity
        // has been edited.
        return 
        (
            other != null &&
            other.OrderId == this.OrderId &&
            other.DisplayAs == this.DisplayAs 
        );
    } 

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Could you detail how it does not work? What `changedContent` ends up containing?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would probably be to contain a `State` property, for instance with the values `New, Saved, Loaded, Modified`. You may also add an `IsDeleted` property.

Then you implement every property set to throw a `PropertyChanged` event, and implement an event handler that automatically sets the `State` property to `Modified`.

Later you can easily query:

```
var modified = entityOrders.Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified);
```

This approach has the advantage of being very deliberate, i.e., you're being explicit and code is readable rather than trying to be hard (and writing way too much and way too complicated code).

In the same fashion you can implement a Delete() method which simply marks the entity as deleted, 
and query all deleted entities as:

```
var deleted = entityOrders.Where(x => x.IsDeleted);
```

or

```
// ignore objects that were created, then deleted, without saving
var deleted = entityOrders.Where(x => x.IsDeleted && x.State != x.New);
```

and all valid data as:

```
var data = entityOrders.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted);
```

Comment: Hi Roy, I agree with you that your solution would be easy to implement and understand, but, alas, our application's architecture does not support it. :(  So, I still need to determine the list of edited items.  I've added a new list, "potentialChanges", which is what is left in the list of orders that the user has created after additions have been removed.  The remaining items may have been edited.  A comparison of the objects from the potentialChanges list against the entityOrders list would provide the objects that have changed. Hopefully, we can fix my linq.  Thanks, again! :)